# How can I validate that the file is correctly uploaded?

Tags: java, grails, upload

I'm using following uploader - http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ . It calls method where I get MultipartFile. The question is: how can I detect the situation that the file is not correctly uploaded - user canceled uploading or something else?

The sample upload server code (it's groovy)

`def upload = {
        File file = createTemporaryFile()
        InputStream inputStream = selectInputStream(request)
        file << inputStream
    }

```
private InputStream selectInputStream(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest) {
        MultipartFile uploadedFile = ((MultipartHttpServletRequest) request).getFile('qqfile')
        return uploadedFile.inputStream
    }
    return request.inputStream
}`
```

Comment: Show us your current upload method (at server side), please.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if there's a 'standard' way, but why not transmit a hash with the file?

Once upload is complete, calculate the hash on the server and see if it matches.